# JOptionPane.showInputDialog() making program crash without error. (window stops responding)

Tags: java, event-handling

This is the line of code I use to call the function

```
String s = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name: ");
```

I've seen on many other forms that adding the "null" argument would fix the problem but it hasn't for me.

This is the block of code I am using.

```
view.getButtonPane().getAddButton().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            String s = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name: ");
            System.out.print("hello");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you mixing Swing and JavaFX?  Both Swing and JavaFX have restrictions on the threads where their methods may be called.

Comment: @VGR Yes I am, how would I solve this issue?

Comment: Use [TextInputDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html) instead of JOptionPane.